# Passiv Konjunktiv II: "...würden die Emails schneller beantwortet werden"

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, passive

Hier ist ein Satz in meinem Grammatikbuch:

> Wenn die Computer nicht dauernd abstürzen würden, würden die Emails schneller beantwortet werden.

gleichfalls:

> Wenn sie größer wäre, würde sie besser gesehen werden.

Ich weiß, "werden + Partizip II" bedeutet Passiv. Aber, kann ich den Satz so formulieren:

> ...würden die Emails schneller beantwortet.

dann in einfacher Weise deutet der Satz sowohl Passiv als auch Konjunktiv II an.

Können Sie mir die Grammatik ein bisschen erklären? Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du hast völlig Recht, beides ist möglich, sowohl

> Wenn ..., würden die Emails schneller beantwortet.

als auch

> Wenn ..., würden die Emails schneller beantwortet werden.

Der Unterschied liegt nur darin, dass bei der ersten Variante der "direkte" Konjunktiv II von *werden* benutzt wird, also *würden*. Bei der zweiten Variante dagegen wird der "bequemere" Ersatzkonjunktiv mit dem Hilfsprädikat *würde* benutzt, also "sie würden ... werden". Das Besondere an dem Beispiel ist nur, dass das Hilfsverb für das Passiv und das für den Konjunktiv das gleiche ist, nämlich verschiedene Formen von *werden*.

Also ist es grammatisch der gleiche Unterschied wie in einem Aktiv-Satz zwischen

> Wenn Geld da wäre, hätten wir bessere Computer.

und

> Wenn Geld da wäre, würden wir bessere Computer haben.

Comment: Danke sehr für Ihr ausführlichen Erklärung!